# creating donuts chart in oracle OBIEE

Tags: oracle, data-visualization, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, obiee

**hello all**

I'm trying to create a donut chart in **OBIEE** from oracle , the version I'm using is : 12.2.1.4.0 .

please note that our OBIEE is located on our organization network and there is no internet access.
so i can't use any solutions that need internet like Google API.

donuts chart sample:

[image]

only pie chart is available:

[image]

Many thanks all ..

Answer (score 0):

Data Visualization has the donut chart type out of the box. It's available in 12.2.1.4.

Comment: Hi Chris,, 
thanks for your reply … yes which is the same as the version I'm using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use D3 to and create this via a narrative but you will need to code it yourself.

To do this you need to

1. Make d3 available on your BI server (I can't remember whether d3.js is already there in 12.2.1.4 or not)
2. Create analysis you want to chart
3. Take code from https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/donut_basic.html and put into narative (remembering to tick the contains HTML check box)

Assuming you have a table that looks something like
| Name | Value |
| ---- | ---- |
| a | 9 |
| b | 20 |
| c | 30 |
| d | 8 |
| e | 12 |

### Prefix

```html
<!-- Load D3 library, need to change URL acccordingly -->
<script src="/analytics/res/[release string]/d3.js" />
<!-- Create div to hold your chart -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<!-- Start my donut chart script -->
<Script>
var data = {
```

### Narrative

```html
@1: @2
```

### Row Separator

```
,
```

### Postfix

```js
}
// the d3 script references above minus the starting <script> tag and the section which sets data
</script>
```

---

### How Does It Work

The key is the narrative bit.   @1 references the first column, @2 the second and so on.
This just builds up the script dynamically so the output would end up looking like
`var data = {a: 9, b: 20, c:30, d:8, e:12}`

You can change this as necessary, add tooltips to display values when you hover over, display a total in the middle etc.

If D3 is not already there (and it is a bit of a faff to find but go to domain home and `find . -name "d3*js"` and see what pops up) then you will need somewhere to make the d3 library available (easy if you have OHS in front of BI) have a look at https://gianniceresa.com/2016/12/deploy-custom-folder-obiee-12c-analyticsres/ to create somewhere to access script locally

### Cons

This approach isn't without cons.   The first one is that you need to code this up in javascript.   It isn't too difficult and there are plenty of examples on the internet but it is obviously more difficult than just creating a normal chart.

Another one is exporting.   As these charts are rendered in the browser and BI just thinks they are html they will not export properly (you will see the raw HTML / javascript)